# Node.js regex replacing multiple attributes in a complex HTML open tag

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am working on a Node.js project, in this project we are searching a bunch of PHP view files, and replacing some of the attributes.
I am trying to get the HTML open tag attribute values, and replace them.

Basically, if this is the tag

```
<tag attr1="[capture ANYTHING inside single/double qoutes]" attr2='[CAPTURE ANYTHING]'></tag>
```

I want to capture anything inside the attribute quotes.
and by `[ANYTHING]` I mean really anything!

**example2**: `attr="with HTML <br/><b>also been captured</b>"`
**example3**: `attr="with line break style \n or \n\r this is still is part of what should been captured and this line too!"`
**example4**: `attr="a PHP code <?php echo $ThisPHPcodeisInsideTheQoutes?> should be captured as well!"`
**example5**: `title="{{angular?'if inside the attribute': 'it should be acptured as well' }}"`

I had wrote the next regex:

> `/<\w+\s+(:?[\w-]+=(:?"|')(.|[\r\n])*?\2\s*?)>?/g`

this regex is catching only the first attribute.

#regex breakdown:

> **`<`** tag start
> **`\w+`** a word, mainly tag name this will force avoiding PHP tags `<?php`
> **`\s+`** a space or multiple sapces `<tag   attr`
> **`(:?`** a non capturing group1, I want to get Multiple attributes, but capture only the content!
> **`[\w-]+`** a word or `-` for example `attr` or `ng-attr`
> **`=`** the attribute equal sign
> **`(:?"|')`** a non capturing group2 open quote or double qoutes
> **`(.|[\r\n])*?`**  -- the actual data I am trying to capture, capture everything `.` or `[\r\n]` line break
> **`\2`** - back reference to  **`(:?"|')`** so well have "[data]" or '[data]'
> **`\s*?`** - zero or more sapces before the next tag not greedy
> **`)`** - close of non capturing group1
> **`>?`** - end of opening tag not greedy

**I don't understand why multiple attributes are not being captured**
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `(:?` is a non-capturing group? `\w` will match the `?` in `<?php`? Are you not allowing spaces before and after the `=`? How are you trying to use this regexp (show code)? `>?` is a non-greedy match (hint: no, it's an optional `>`).

Comment: @torazaburo please run it in a regex editor, you will see that your comment is wrong , you may see it here:  
http://refiddle.com/refiddles/57c80c5275622d7947c11600

Comment: Which comment do you mean? I don't need to use a regexp editor to know that `(:?` is **not** a non-capturing group; it's a group starting with an optional `:`. You probably meant `(?:`. This could possibly be the reason for your regexp not capturing multiple attributes.

Comment: Where is your closing quote? What is `\2` supposed to refer to, since you're (trying) not to capture the group containing the quotes, right?

Comment: try this will help you :    https://regex101.com/r/xA7uN8/3

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar
Your solution will capture PHP tags, and there is no back reference to the open quote: 
https://regex101.com/r/fY1oB0/4
But thanks

Comment: @torazaburo \2 refer to the opening quote/double
You can see that it's working great in the fiddler I had published with the question.

Comment: BY definition, a back-reference does NOT work with a non-capturing group. It works for you only because you are writing the non-capturing group INCORRECTLY as `(:?`, which, as I said an hour ago, is NOT a non-capturing group, but rather a capturing group starting with an optional colon. If you love the regexp editors so much, please review CAREFULLY their narrative description of your `(:?` construct.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, fixed my query.

Comment: Use a proper parser...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is possible to do with a single regex match. As far as I am aware, you cannot match multiple **sub**patterns using a backreference end.

Instead, I would recommend processing the HTML in two steps. First, extract the opening tag string using

```
/<\w+\s+[\w-]+=("|')(?:.|[\r\n])*?\1\s+.*?>/g
```

and then go back through the matches and extract each of the attribute/value pairs using

```
/([\w-]+=("|')(?:.|[\r\n])*?\2)/g
```

At that point, you can split on the first "=" to break apart each attribute from its value.

[Here is a fiddle implementing what I recommend.](https://jsfiddle.net/chadlieberman/es7nxq3k/) Your sample text should parse out the way you want it.